# Shimano T610 hub with 9 speed casette - I need spacer ring?

Tags: shimano, hub

If I would to use the Shimano deore T610 hub with 9 speed casette (hg400 11-32) - I need spacer ring? If yes, what size?

Answer (score 2):

No spacer ring is required, as T610 is a 8-10 speed hub.

Shimano freehub widths have been:

- 7 speed width: you can only mount 7 speed cassettes
- 8-10 speed width: you can mount 8-10 speed cassettes and 11-speed "MTB" cassettes in which case the big sprocket overhangs the right hub flange
- 11-speed "road" width: you can mount 11-speed "road" cassettes without a spacer and 8-10 speed "road" cassettes and 8-11-speed "MTB" cassettes with a 1.85mm spacer

I don't think official spacers to run 7 speed cassettes on more modern hubs are available, but it may be possible to make your own.

Further complicating matters is that some 10-speed "road" cassettes with aluminum spider (such as CS-7800 and CS-7900) require an additional 1mm spacer to run on 8-10 speed hubs. If you run such a cassette on 11-speed "road" hub then you need the 1mm spacer and the 1.85mm spacer together.

Comment: Actually, 7 speed cassettes can be mounted on 8-10 speed hubs with a 4.5mm spacer; there are some things to watch out for, as described online, for example here: https://bike.bikegremlin.com/1259/bicycle-rear-hub-compatibility/ sheldonbrown.com is always a good source for such interoperability questions.

Comment: Yes, that might be possible but I haven't seen the 4.5mm spacers for sale anywhere.